# Add multiple geopoints and markers automatically in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to make the addition of a geopoint in a map more "automatic"? I mean, if we have many points to add in the map (more than 100), we don't have to add them one by one like that:

```
GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(36.86774),microdegrees(10.305302));
GeoPoint point3 = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(36.87154),microdegrees(10.341815));
GeoPoint point4 = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(36.876093),microdegrees(10.325716));  

pinOverlay.addPoint(point2);
pinOverlay.addPoint(point3);
pinOverlay.addPoint(point4);
```

Is there a method to stock them all in a table and then the compiler adds them one by one?

Comment: Have you considered a for loop?

Comment: @Manish Burman:And where i store the long and lat values ? (Thanks for adding a -1 to my post :\).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to store them in either a SQLite database or some other form of data storage, and then you can pull them in and place them on the map with an ItemizedOverlay, see *[Google Map View](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)* (a tutorial).

**Create your array from a database cursor**

```
Cursor cursor =  mDbHelper.getItems();
cursor.moveToFirst();

List<CatchItem> catchList = new ArrayList<CatchItem>();

if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        CatchItem item = new CatchItem();

        item.Latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
        item.Longitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude"));

        catchList.add(item);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

**ItemizedOverlay**

```
List<Overlay> overlays = mMaps.getOverlays();
overlays.clear();
CatchesItemizedOverlay catchOverlays = new CatchesItemizedOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_markeroverlay_blue72), this);

for (int i = 0; i < catchList.size(); i++) {
    double lat = catchList.get(i).Latitude;
    double lng = catchList.get(i).Longitude;

    GeoPoint geopoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6), (int)(lng*1E6));
    catchOverlays.addOverlay(new CatchOverlayItem(this, geopoint, catchList.get(i)));
}

overlays.add(catchOverlays);
```

`CatchesItemizedOverlay` is my own extended `ItemizedOverlay` (I needed custom functionality). The catchList object is just a custom object that has latitude and longitude.

Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: Oukay, thanks for editing the answer, i'll test this code :).

Comment: And how to add items on catchList ? This code is just to get values.

Comment: It all depends on how you store your location data.  I store mine in a SQLite DB and populate my objects prior to this code.  There's a good example of using SQLite at http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Okay, so to conclude i must set up a SQlite database to store on it the 2 values(lat and long) then to fix them in map i have to use this code(that hopefully it'll work). Ouf, i have some work to do :\. Thank you for your answer. ACCEPTED :D.

Comment: Thanks.  I added code to create your array once you get a cursor of your lat/long items from a SQLite DB.  Enjoy.

Comment: i implemented an SQlite DB. But i want to know what is CatchItem in your example. And getItems() function what is its code ? I'm stucking now on this 2 errors. Need your answer please. I almost completed it.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could store them in a SQLite databse, and pull them as needed

Comment: Wow, the things will be harder to make so :\.

Comment: Right...Or you could do use a AsyncTask, and use onProgressUpdate()

Comment: Please look at hooked82, i think it's simpler. No ?

Comment: hooked82 does find a better solution. This will make things a little less complicated. Try it out and see =)