# How can I add search places to favourites in Android maps?

Tags: android, maps

I want add search places to favourites in Android maps program. I am getting the search place successfully, how can I add it to the favourites list.

Please share some sample code or give some instructions

Comment: use SQLIte to store your Search.

Comment: how can get the maps data ? is there any sample to store into db ?

Comment: what you are getting  in Search , i think you are getting lat and long of location so you can add that in to database and later you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you get your search place result you can store it's data as one row in database for example you can get idea from this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113980/add-multiple-geopoints-and-markers-automatically-in-google-maps).

For use of SQLite in android refer this [Link Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

you can also refer this for [get Geo-point from SQlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121924/get-geopoints-from-sqlite-db)

Comment: Hi Herry i am using the  Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=")); this intent is used to get the source and destination directory how can get lat and Lang for submit to Sqllite database?

Comment: i think is to draw path between source and destination.

Comment: yes how can i search and get  the lat and Lang positions  for location to submit to the database?

Comment: For that you need to use this google api search https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CmRYAAAAciqGsTRX1mXRvuXSH2ErwW-jCINE1aLiwP64MCWDN5vkXvXoQGPKldMfmdGyqWSpm7BEYCgDm-iv7Kc2PF7QA7brMAwBbAcqMr5i1f4PwTpaovIZjysCEZTry8Ez30wpEhCNCXpynextCld2EBsDkRKsGhSLayuRyFsex6JA6NPh9dyupoTH3g&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Comment: i use this one appending my api key it does not show the any places in mY emulator?

Comment: url that you use it does not have api key so it will not show any result.

Comment: I appended API key it asks sd card to download json.bin how can i check it is working or not ?

Comment: you can run that url in browser like google crome and see that any json data is showing or not?

Comment: my need is when i type the name of the place it shows in the maps and save that place lat and lang positions to sqllite and shows in the list ?

Comment: you can use this example for your required output in which it search by location name and return result according to that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375654/how-to-implement-google-maps-search-by-address-in-android

Comment: in which for geocoder that return addresses or some thing else.

Comment: which give you that can you add that in question ?

Comment: 04-30 17:01:23.448: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: 04-30 17:01:23.448: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(580): java.lang.NullPointerException there are the exceptions i am getting

Comment: hi by this i can serach and display the adress in the how can i get the lat and lang to display in tHe database

Comment: Hi Herry i want display places in the favorites is like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=streetdirectory.mobile&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInN0cmVldGRpcmVjdG9yeS5tb2JpbGUiXQ..